# handle hive partitioned table running beyond physical memory limits

Tags: hive, hadoop-partitioning

I have to create a hive partitioned table but it is running beyond physical memory limits. 
Is there a way to handle this issue . I cant change container memory neither use less data from source. 
Will temporary tables help here i.e. creating 12 temp tables for 12 months and then feeding them to the partition table. But I dont know how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post us the hiveQL you are using and the exact error message please?

Comment: Error:Container [pid=15766,containerID=container_e49_1512455534887_24762_01_000011] is running beyond physical memory limits